# C++(3364) : operator -> or ->* applied instead of pointer type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdmap, std-pair, allocator

I have declared and populated a map : `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<float>>>>> data;`.

I have a print function to print the contents of the map which is as follows :

```
void print() {
    for (auto it : data) {
        std::cout << it->first << "\n";
        for (auto iter : it->second) {
            std::cout << iter->first << "\n";
            for (auto val : iter->second) {
                std::cout << val->second << "";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

But, when I compile the program, I get the following error :

```
operator -> or ->* applied to "std::pair<const std::string,
std::vector<std::pair<std::string,
std::vector<std::vector<float, 
std::allocator<float>>, 
std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>>>>, 
std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, 
std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>, 
std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>>>>>>>" 
instead of to a pointer typeC/C++(3364)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I also tried accessing the map data through `(*it).first`, which throws the following error :

```
no operator "*" matches these operandsC/C++(349)
myfile.cpp(80, 23): operand types are: * std::pair<const std::string, 
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<float, 
std::allocator<float>>, std::allocator<std::vector<float, 
std::allocator<float>>>>>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, 
std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>, 
std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>>>>>>>
```

What should I do instead of what I have did? Please let me know if I'm wrong anywhere in the code.

Comment: When iterating using a range based for loop, it doesn't return an iterator type, it returns the actual type. use: it.first

Comment: As well as the comment above, you seem to have one too many nested vectors of `float`. In your innermost loop, `val` is a `vector<float>` not a `float`, so, even changing to `std::cout << val.second << "";` will give an error.

Comment: Nesting containers to the level you have done is extremely prone to errors; you should consider rethinking/redesigning your data type.

Comment: (In my first comment, I meant that `val` is a `vector<float>` not a `pair<string,float>`.)

Comment: I don't know what you are coding, but that data structure (the map) doesn't look easy to work with, at least it's not readable. Maybe you should consider a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to unroll your map, you made several mistakes. You need to go from outer to inner structures.

And you need to understand that using a range based for loop already unrolls one level.

In order to learn it, you should avoid to use the `auto` key word, because then you *must* name the correct data type.

All the above will lead to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
using namespace std::string_literals;

std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<float>>>>> data{
    {"OuterMapS1"s, {  {"v1PairLeft1"s, {{1.1f,2.2f},{3.3f,4.4f}}},{"v2PairLeft2"s, {{5.5f,6.6f,7.7f},{1.2f,1.3f}}}}},
    {"OuterMapS2"s, {  {"v3PairLeft3"s, {{7.0f,8.0f,9.0f},{3.5f,4.6f}}},{"v4PairLeft4"s, {{3.5f,3.6f,3.7f},{4.2f,4.3f,4.4f}}}}}
};

int main() {
    for (const std::pair<const std::string,std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::vector<std::vector<float>>>>>& p1 : data) {
        std::cout << p1.first << '\n';
        for (const std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<float>>>& p2 : p1.second) {
            std::cout << '\t' << p2.first << '\n';
            for (const std::vector<float> &vOuter : p2.second) { 
                std::cout << "\t\t\t";
                for (const float& f : vOuter) {
                    std::cout << f << '\t';
                }
                std::cout << '\n';
            }
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

Additionally, to define your own types with the `using` statement will also be helpful. Then you can first build your data structure from inside out. And, for printing, you can use the predefined types.

This will make life a little bit simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
using namespace std::string_literals;

using FloatVec = std::vector<float>;
using Float2dVec = std::vector<FloatVec>;
using PairStr2dFloatVec = std::pair<std::string, Float2dVec>;
using VecPairStr2dFloatVec = std::vector<PairStr2dFloatVec>;
using MyMap = std::map<std::string, VecPairStr2dFloatVec>;
using MyMapPair = MyMap::value_type;

MyMap data{
    {"OuterMapS1"s, {  {"v1PairLeft1"s, {{1.1f,2.2f},{3.3f,4.4f}}},{"v2PairLeft2"s, {{5.5f,6.6f,7.7f},{1.2f,1.3f}}}}},
    {"OuterMapS2"s, {  {"v3PairLeft3"s, {{7.0f,8.0f,9.0f},{3.5f,4.6f}}},{"v4PairLeft4"s, {{3.5f,3.6f,3.7f},{4.2f,4.3f,4.4f}}}}}
};

int main() {
    for (const MyMapPair& p1 : data) {
        std::cout << p1.first << '\n';
        for (const PairStr2dFloatVec& p2 : p1.second) {
            std::cout << '\t' << p2.first << '\n';
            for (const FloatVec& vOuter : p2.second) {
                std::cout << "\t\t\t";
                for (const float& f : vOuter) {
                    std::cout << f << '\t';
                }
                std::cout << '\n';
            }
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

And, last but not least, you can use structured bindings for `std::map` and `std::pair`, this time with `auto` again, but again, a bit more readable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
using namespace std::string_literals;

using FloatVec = std::vector<float>;
using Float2dVec = std::vector<FloatVec>;
using PairStr2dFloatVec = std::pair<std::string, Float2dVec>;
using VecPairStr2dFloatVec = std::vector<PairStr2dFloatVec>;
using MyMap = std::map<std::string, VecPairStr2dFloatVec>;
using MyMapPair = MyMap::value_type;

MyMap data{
    {"OuterMapS1"s, {  {"v1PairLeft1"s, {{1.1f,2.2f},{3.3f,4.4f}}},{"v2PairLeft2"s, {{5.5f,6.6f,7.7f},{1.2f,1.3f}}}}},
    {"OuterMapS2"s, {  {"v3PairLeft3"s, {{7.0f,8.0f,9.0f},{3.5f,4.6f}}},{"v4PairLeft4"s, {{3.5f,3.6f,3.7f},{4.2f,4.3f,4.4f}}}}}
};

int main() {
    for (const auto& [outerString, outerVector] : data) {
        std::cout << outerString << '\n';
        for (const auto& [innerString, nextVector] : outerVector) {
            std::cout << '\t' << innerString << '\n';
            for (const FloatVec& fVector : nextVector) {
                std::cout << "\t\t\t";
                for (const float& f : fVector) {
                    std::cout << f << '\t';
                }
                std::cout << '\n';
            }
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the complicated data structure will make it a bit difficult to access sub-elements.